# RestKit & Core Data - Reloading data in table view nested in a view container

Tags: core-data, notifications, restkit

I'm working on a sync process where the latest changed objects are loaded from a server with RestKit using a timestamp and saving all changes using Core Data based on the MOC idea.

**Sequence**
1) Starting the sync process and save changes to Core Data [AppDelegate]
2) Refetching data from Core Data after process is finished and reload data [ContactTableView]
3) Reloading input views when fetch is complete  [ContactDetailView]
4) Reloading table view placed in ViewContainer inside of ContactDetailView [ContactDetailTV]

**Passing data between views**

```
ContactTableView (passing object when user selects row)
--» ContactDetailView (passing object to subView in viewContainer)
    --» ContactDetailTV (displaying data of object in a tableView)
```

**Problem**
*That works*
When I'm inside of ContactTableView the table view is reloaded with the new fetched data and everything is fine.

*That doesn't work*
When I'm inside of ContactDetailTV (because the data can change when I'm looking at it) the view displays the old data inside of the ContactDetailTV even after calling [self.tableView reloadData].

**Question**
What am I doing wrong or what is missing to get the reloading to work like expected?

---

*Code*

**AppDelegate**

```
- (void)startSyncProcess:(NSInteger)operationCode
{        
// Init helper
syncCount = 0;
syncProcess = 0;

switch (operationCode) 
{
    default:
        // (1) Request deleted companys from server
        [self requestDeletedCompanysFromServer];
        break;

    case 0:
        // (2) Request deleted contacts from server
        [self requestDeletedContactsFromServer];
        break;

    case 1:
        // (2) Request edited companys from server
        [self requestEditedCompanysFromServer];
        break;

    case 2:
        // (2) Request edited contacts from server
        [self requestEditedContactsFromServer];
        break;

    case 3:
        // Reload data views
        [self saveCurrentSyncTime];            

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateTableViewAfterSave" object:self];
        break;
}
}
```

**ContactTableView**

```
- (void)syncContextDidSave:(NSNotification*)saveNotification 
{   
   // Handling the "updateTableViewAfterSave"-notification by refetching the data with Core Data
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) 
         NSLog(@"[ERROR] Saving failed with error: %@", [error userInfo]);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateSubViewAfterSave" object:nil];
}
```

**ContactDetailTV**

```
- (void)updateSubViewAfterSave:(NSNotification *)saveNotification
{
    // Handling the "updateSubViewAfterSave"-notification by updating the table view that displays the data without using a fetchedResultsController
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the object with the newest data from Core Data (because even when refetching the data, the context of the fetchedController keeps a "snapshot" of the object), I had to update the method.

```
- (void)updateSubViewAfterSave:(NSNotification *)saveNotification
{
    // Handling the "updateSubViewAfterSave"-notification by updating the table view that displays the data without using a fetchedResultsController

    id appDelegate = (id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    NSManagedObjectContext *tempContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    [tempContext refreshObject:contact mergeChanges:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```